# Access Android/data on parental-restricted phone

Tags: backup, file-system, parental-control

I'm looking for a way to backup a Minecraft PE worlds on a phone that has parental-control enabled (best in an automated way).

The Minecraft on Android has the ability to save the worlds in the "External" location, which in the newest version is in `/Android/data/com.mojang.minecraftpe/files/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds`.

Unfortunately, on parental-restricted phone, I cannot access `/Android/data/` folder at all. I tried via Samsung's "My Files" app, as well as FX File Explorer - the prompt for "Use this folder" does not appear.

How can I get those files, so I'm able to push them to cloud for backup?

Comment: Have you tried to get access to those folder using a PC and connect the phone via USB?

Comment: Yeah, that's one way it worked. But I went with installing a dedicated app for MCPE backups. It did produce the "Use this folder" prompt, so now I started to think that maybe Samsung's "My Files" / FX Explorer use some kind of deprecated API, or they are bugged?